# How to use Rbind when datasets I am using have different names in the variables, but they each mean the same thing

Tags: r, dataset, rename, rbind

I am having a hard time combining these datasets and it's because the names of the variables are different. How would I do this?

[I want to combine this, but the response I get from R is "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
names do not match previous names"]

[image: img]

Also, I understand that some of the variables are named differently but they mean the same thing. I do have the same number of variables in each dataset.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We cannot read code or data into R from images. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including code and a small representative dataset in a plain text format.

Comment: `data.table::rbindlist(list(dat1, dat2, dat3),  use.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Hello.  Have you tried just renaming them to have a consistent name scheme?

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily convert the dataframes to matrices and switch back after `rbind`ing:

```
econ1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2)
econ2 <- data.frame(c = "a", d = NA)


list(econ1, econ2) |>
  Map(f = as.matrix) |>
  Reduce(f = rbind) |>
  as.data.frame()
```

```
  a    b
1 1    2
2 a <NA>
```

Note that names will be taken from the first dataframe in line, and modes (`numeric`, `character` ...) will be changed to accomodate all incoming data. E. g. column `a` in above example is `character`.

Comment: This approach should not be recommended for the very reasons you note (and more). Much better to standardize the names and then bind.